# How to implement user based views

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, view

I would like to have a team site that changes based on the user that is logged in. The team site is supposed to be a landing page for everyone in the company to start their day. How can I set it up such that when a user logs in, their "dashboard" loads with their set up containing: their own document library for file storage, a personal calendar that is relevant to them (sync to their office365 calendar would be great), and then a link to everyone else's storage so that a file can be accessed from any account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each web part on the page, set the view and filter whichever field is relevant equal to `[Me]`. So for example, for the document library, set the home page view to `Created By = [Me]`. Then set the property bar (or your own link in a content edit web part) to take them to the full document library with a default view that isn't filtered.

Comment: If this is the case and we store all of their documents in one library and just change the view, wouldn't that document library get slowed down fairly quick if everyone is adding in documents?

Comment: No, the only issue would be is if 2 people are working on the exact same document at the same time, but that's true in a small library. You'll run into view issues at 5000+ documents, but as long as you can create views on indexed columns that have fewer than 5000 documents/view, you'll be fine.

Comment: well, we are looking to have this be a long term storage and I'm not sure the project managers will not use 5000 documents each. Do you see a workaround for this?

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't be using a team site, but rather creating a document center (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-numbers-of-files-by-using-a-Document-Center-c011a29f-053b-4194-8036-1dbcf0e7af34) and maybe the Relevant Document web part.

Comment: Quick clarification, what do you mean by "property bar" in your first comment?

Comment: I'm not sure for the life of me why I called it that. I meant the web part chrome header on the title of the library. (Clicking the bar outside of the words doesn't work... I run into that frequently with my users.)